# How to get the String and its line position from byte[]

Tags: java, regex

SUppose I have a String like below:

```
static String MSG = "4: \n"+
        ":xx:xyz\n"+
        ":xx:abcdef\n"+ 
        ":xx:axvavsba\n"+ 
        ":xx:/000000000000\n"+ 
        ":xxs:/abcssd\n"+ 
        "efg\n"+ 
        "ijk\n"+ 
        "lmn\n"+ 
        "pqr\n"+ 
        ":xx:asasasasas";
```

from this I want to convert into

```
byte[] messageBytes = MSG.getBytes("utf-8");
```

and from the `messageBytes`, I want to extract string based on the position along with its line number

for example if I will give `extract(startIndex, endIndex)` it should return original string in that position along with its line number

Here Line number I am refering is each string inside `::` reffers to one line number

I tried using

```
String str = new String(ArrayUtils.subarray(messageByte, startIndex, endIndex), "utf-8");
```

I am able to retrive the string but how can I extract the respective line number.

ANy help on this will be appricated.

Purpose of doing this is as a string might contatin some `japanese` charecters so if I will apply `regex`  then I will not get the exact string so to accomplish the same job I am trying this approach.

Any suggestion or new approach will be also good.

Comment: What do startIndex and endIndex exactly mean? Byte positions? Char positions? of the string? may be part of a line? Remember the number of bytes that are a single character is variable in utf-8. Most are 1 byte and accented chars are usually 2 bytes but I think they can be more than 2.

Comment: You better use UTF-16 since you know each character is 2 bytes and you can random 'jump' to every even position and be sure a character starts there. In UTF-8 you might at the position of the second byte of a character.

Comment: startindex and endIndex is basically for byte postion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sample code

```
System.out.println(findStringAndPosition(MSG));
```

#### Output

```
xx found at line 2
xx found at line 3
xx found at line 4
xx found at line 5
xxs found at line 6
xx found at line 11
```

#### Details

```
public static Informations findStringAndPosition(String input) {
    Informations infos = new Informations();
    String[] lines = input.split("\n");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^:([^:]+):.*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("");

    int lineNumber = 0;
    for (String line : lines) {
        lineNumber++;
        m.reset(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            infos.add(new Info(lineNumber, m.group(1)));
        }
    }

    return infos;
}

static class Informations extends ArrayList<Info> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2872174623287128687L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Info info : this) {
            sb.append(String.format("%s found at line %s\n", info.getString(), info.getPosition()));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}

static class Info {
    private String string;
    private int position;

    public Info(int position, String string) {
        this.string = string;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public final String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public final int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```